# Is this a -webkit-box-reflect bug

Tags: html, css

While I developing a div image box with reflection -webkit-box-reflect, I found out that the reflection at bottom not mirroring exactly from the bottom of the image. It depends on how much size available for the reflection.

For better illustration of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/4B26Q/14/

The 2 images have the different reflection, one from the middle and one from bottom of the image, which I expect reflection is from the bottom. The reflection is somehow depends on how much html height available, it the space allow for full shadow display, it will reflect the image at the bottom (you can adjust the slider of the html panel to adjust the size).

Is there a way to fix the reflection start from the bottom of the image regardless of space available?

Comment: Have you checked webkit's bug tracker? If you file a report, it could help. They will mark it as a dupe if they have seen it before, which may help find a work around also.

Answer (score 2):

Try the same code by removing width and height in box1  and box2 as follows:

```
#box1{
position:fixed;
margin-left:20%;
margin-top:0%;
-webkit-box-reflect: below;
}
```